# Eclipse C++ console print order linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, console

I know there many subjects about this but none of them helps me.

I use in my C/C++ project `std::cout` and `std::cerr` to print info (cout) or error (cerr).
But when executing it  they don't print in the right order, they seems to "group print". Sometime all cerr then all cout and sometime all cout first then all cerr.

I tried to `flush()` after every line, don't work. (luckily, it would be awful having to use it every time ...).
Also tried `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` same issue...

If run program directly in linux's console, order is good but eclipse console more useful due to colors.

Here code sample

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cerr << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    std::cerr << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    std::cerr << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    std::cerr << __LINE__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << __LINE__ << std::endl;
}
```

And console print

```
11
12
14
15
13
16
```

==> Wrong order ...
In this example cerr comes out before cout

Comment: This is most likely a problem with eclipse. `std::endl` actually causes a `flush()` FYI

Comment: Why do you expect, that text printed to two different streams has a defined sequence in which it will appear? There is no guarantee and it working on the console is probably an implementation detail. Why not just print it to the same stream and prefix "Info:" and "Error:" or something like that, then it is guaranteed to work.

Comment: I would also try to use locks (mutexes) for each call and see how it behaves.

Comment: You may consider using an ordinary terminal (after all, it's more portable) alongside with this: http://serverfault.com/questions/59262/bash-print-stderr-in-red-color to get colors. But still, yes, two output streams can interleave as they (or Eclipse in this case) wish.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the situation is as follows, `std::cout` is added into a buffor, and `std::cerr` does not. `std::cerr` is faster and it does not need to be flushed. Also `std::cerr` and `std::cout` uses different streams.

The problem here is that `std::cerr` shows right away and `std:cout` needs to be flushed before it's showed.

Comment: `std::endl` flushes the stream, so the line numbers should always be printed in order.